# android emulator error permission error for writing to sdcard

Tags: android, android-emulator, filesystems

Im having an error when uploading data to the sdcard of the emulator

> Failed to push selection: Read-only file system

I can see the sdcard on the DDMS file explorer

so I have seen answers to this problem suggesting to do in adb shell:

```
# mount -o remount rw /sdcard
mount: Invalid argument

//so i check with mount only
  # mount
rootfs / rootfs ro 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,cpu 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock0 /system yaffs2 ro 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock1 /data yaffs2 rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock2 /cache yaffs2 rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

so what im i missing?, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `sdcard` mounted. Make sure you've added sdcard to your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone... I figured out the reason behind this problem.
When your emulator OS boots, go to *Developer Settings* and enable *USB debugging*. Then try again:

```
adb shell
mount -o remount rw /sdcard
```

Hope this works!